# jQuery closest() and/or find() not working dynamic datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am having the idea that `closest()` and `find()` are not working on a dynamic `datatable`. I am trying to get the `ID` in the first `<td>` element in the same row, but it keeps getting back empty.

```js
var idOfTheProperty = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
```

```html
<tr>
  <td><span>999</span</td>
  <td>somewhere.com/idOfTheProperty</td>
<tr>
```

The `datatable` is made in here:

```
<div class="kt-datatable" id="json_data"></div>
```

Any idea how to change my jQuery code to make it work?

Comment: Can you please add the code to snippet here to get more idea about the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
$(document).on("click","#json_data tbody tr, #json_data tbody tr td",function(){
   var idOfTheProperty = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
   console.log(idOfTheProperty);
})
```

For onload you can try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#reportsSentList").find("tbody tr").each(function(key,value){
      var idOfTheProperty = 
$(value).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
      console.log(idOfTheProperty);
   });

})
```

Comment: That indeed is working! Thank you! But how am I able to run this on load instead of the click? I want to print it on load on each row.

Comment: @Erik180486: I updated the code. Please try this and please upvote is it usefull

Comment: @Erik180486: Let us know if the issue is solved. Please accept the answer if the issue is solved